# What exactly to test (unittest) in a larger function containing several dataframe manipulations

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-unittest

Perhaps this is a constraint of my understanding of unittests, but I get quite confused as to what should be tested, patched, etc in a method that has several pandas dataframe manipulations. Many of the unittest examples out there focus on classes and methods that are typically small. For larger methods, I get a bit lost on the typical unittest paradigm. For example:

myscript.py

```
class Pivot:
    def prepare_dfs(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(self.file, sep=self.delimiter)
        g = df.groupby("Other_Location")
        df1 = g.apply(lambda x: x[x["PRN"] == "Free"].count())

        locations = ["O12-03-01", "O12-03-02"]
        cp = df1["PRN"]
        cp = cp[locations].tolist()
        data = [locations, cp]

        new_df = pd.DataFrame({"Other_Location": data[0], "Free": data[1]})

        return new_df, df
```

test_myscript.py

```
class TestPivot(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        args = parse_args(["-f", "test1", "-d", ","])
        self.pivot = Pivot(args)
        self.pivot.path = "Pivot/path"

    @mock.patch("myscript.cp[locations].tolist()", return_value=None)
    @mock.patch("myscript.pd.read_csv", return_value=df)
    def test_prepare_dfs_1(self, mock_read_csv, mock_cp):
        new_df, df = self.pivot.prepare_dfs()
# Here I get a bit lost
```

For example here I try to circumvent the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myscript.cp[locations]'; 'myscript' is not a package
```

I managed to mock correctly the `pd.read_csv` in my method, however further down in the code there are `groupy`, `apply`, `tolist` etc. The error message is thrown at the following line:

```
cp = cp[locations].tolist()
```

What is the best way to approach unittesting when your method involves several manipulations on a dataframe? Is refactoring the code always advised (into smaller chunks)? In this case, how can I mock correctly the `tolist ?`